# How to solve "Step definition is not found" error: StepDefinitionNotFoundError

Tags: pytest, python-behave

Here is my feature file - a.feature:

```
Scenario Outline: Some outline
    Given something
    When <thing> is moved to <position>
    Then something else

    Examples:
    | thing | position |
    |   1   |    1     |
```

and save it in /tmp/a.feature

Here is my pytest step file (/tmp/a.py):

```
from pytest_bdd import (                                                                                                                    
    given,
    scenario,
    then,
    when,
)

@scenario('./x.feature', 'Some outline')
def test_some_outline():
    """Some outline."""


@given('something')
def something():
    """something."""
    pass


@when('<thing> is moved to <position>')
def thing_is_moved_to_position(thing, position):
    assert isinstance(thing, int)
    assert isinstance(position, int)

@then('something else')
def something_else():
    """something else."""
    pass
```

When I run it:

```
$ pwd
/tmp

$ pytest ./a.py

............
............

E                   pytest_bdd.exceptions.StepDefinitionNotFoundError: Step definition is not found: When "1 is moved to 1". Line 3 in scenario "Some outline" in the feature "/tmp/x.feature"

/home/cyan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_bdd/scenario.py:192: StepDefinitionNotFoundError

============= short test summary info =============

FAILED x.py::test_some_outline[1-1] - pytest_bdd.exceptions.StepDefinitionNotFoundError: Step definition is not found: When "1 is moved to 1". Line 3 in scenario "Some outli...

============ 1 failed in 0.09s ============
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the step definition:

```
@when('<thing> is moved to <position>')
def thing_is_moved_to_position(thing, position):
    assert isinstance(thing, int)
    assert isinstance(position, int)
```

And use this sintax:

```
@when('{thing} is moved to {position}')
def thing_is_moved_to_position(thing, position):
    assert isinstance(thing, int)
    assert isinstance(position, int)
```

And in the Scenario, instead of:

```
When <thing> is moved to <position>
```

try to use:

```
When "<thing>" is moved to "<position>"
```

It works for me in this way.